# PHP exec don't run program

Tags: php, exec, raspbian

I want to start program when I enter my webpage, and problem is in permissions(??) because when I try

```
echo exec('whoami');
```

I've got valid response (www-data) but when i try code like it:

```
echo exec('/var/www/./sitesend');
```

and

```
echo passthru(/var/www/./sitesend');
```

I got no response. I tried to

```
chown www-data /var/www/sitesend
chmod 755 /var/www/sitesend
```

My C++ app runs correctly, and its sending by NRF infromations to turn lights.
But not work, when enter page app won't run and I don't get any reps in echo.

Comment: what does that have to do with C++?

Comment: Send by NRF code to turn the light. Show c++ code ?

Comment: @SURViR Does your c++ program run correctly when you start it in the console?

Comment: Yeah, it runs correct

Comment: Exec will not show you any response from the program unless you pass in a second variable for the output. Try using [passthru](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) instead.

Comment: Same effect - Don't do anything, I don't want any response, response is now for test. I want to my app run

Comment: Can you update your question to include that information as at the moment it appears the fact you do not get any response is the problem.

Comment: @Anigel This should be an answer!

Comment: I updated question now, maybe www-data don't have permission to use GPIO, but i don't know how to give it.

Comment: @Anigel Pointing towards `passthru` was correct and you where the first who said that. I just wanted to encourage you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a conclusive answer, but you can try a number of things:

- Try the follow command to see if www-data may run the command.

  ```
  sudo -u www-data /var/www/sitesend
  ```
- Try running a PHP script with the `passthru` command from the commandline.
- See if you're running [AppArmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor) for the Apache process. AppArmor will block execution for files not white listed.

  ```
  ls /etc/apparmor.d
  ```